# Woocommerce terms and conditions with variable

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

Is there a way to send products, tax, prices and the payment method informations to another page from checkout page without submitting order? I want "terms and conditions" link which is near "submit button" open a new page like the image below;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ51f.png

I searched over checkout folder of woocommerce and I couldn't find any solution for that. It sends data to thank you page after submitting. Should I send same data to terms page without submitting order? There is a form-pay.php in that folder but it's form has no action also.

Comment: Considered using JS to grab the information from the checkout page and filling in the blanks on a pop up, rather then a new page?

Comment: @Practically Yes it is considerable. But I have only little php experience and no JS. I saw there are JS files doing this job in woocommerce but they are meaningless for me :)